# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr 64-bit hashes cannot be positively verified against the ubuntu public key

Tags: 14.04, gnupg

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr 64-bit ISO from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=US&version=14.04&architecture=amd64) and all the hashes from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/). I checked downloaded ISO against the provided hashes (MD5SUMS, SHA1SUMS, SHA256SUMS). Everything was correct. Any integrity issues were revealed.

**Unfortunately, I cannot positively verify given hashes against the Ubuntu public key.** I had gpg installed, so I imported FBB75451 key from `keyserver.ubuntu.com`.

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0xFBB75451
gpg: requesting key FBB75451 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key FBB75451: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0 valid: 2 signed: 12 trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 2u
gpg: depth: 1 valid: 12 signed: 8 trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 6m, 6f, 0u
gpg: depth: 2 valid: 4 signed: 4 trust: 1-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 3f, 0u
gpg: depth: 3 valid: 1 signed: 0 trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 1f, 0u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2008-04-14
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg: imported: 1
```

**However, when the command $ gpg --verify MD5SUMS.gpg MD5SUMS is put into terminal, the result is as follows:**

```
gpg: Signature made Sat 19 Apr 2014 12:38:11 AM CEST using DSA key ID FBB75451
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"
```

**Could you explain me why gpg previews bad signature? What went wrong?**

Thank you for your responses.

---

I downloaded the checksums once again an hour ago and everything was verified positively. What was the cause of my problem, I don't know. :)

Comment: Maybe your MD5SUMS got corrupted in transit (without altering the checksum for your .iso). My MD5SUMS file has the following MD5 checksum: `7754c5b101698bfa0ef3074f6c1a4036`.

Comment: @jonasmalacofilho The correct MD5 checksum for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr 64-bit is `dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153` (source: [Ubuntu] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). I don't know which version you are using, but your hash is not even listed.

Comment: I was talking about the MD5 hash for the MD5SUMS file, that probably got corrupted on your first download.

Comment: @Christianus maybe you should consider **downloading via torrent** since **Transmission-GTK** has a method to verify downloads and you don't have to re-download the whole thing again in case of inconsistencies